# How do I make ElasticSearch Client available application wide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I am using `elasticsearch_ruby` within a Rails App. I chose not to use `elasticsearch_rails` because I do not want such tight integration with my ActiveRecord objects.

Using `elasticsearch_ruby` and `elasticsearch_transport`, a new client is created like this:

```
client = ElasticSearch::Client.new(log:true)
```

How do I make this client accessible application wide. 
I only want to create the instance once and then use it application wide.

What is the best practice for doing this?

It seems that there is something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an initializer 
 1. Create a file under `configuration/initializer/elasticsearch.rb` 
 2. Initialize your client like `$elasticsearch_client=ElasticSearch::Client.new(log:true)` 
 3. Use this `$elasticsearch_client` anywhere in your rails app

Comment: Is this the approach that is mostly accepted by users of elasticsearch_ruby.

Comment: I don't know about users of `elasticsearch_ruby`. But this is the way used for `Redis` to be available for the entire app.

Comment: @JohnLinux  feel free to share the results of the proposed solution